# UIBubbleTableView issue with iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone-6-plus, uibubbletableview

I have been using `UIBubbleTableView` for about two years now without much problem.

Today I checked it on iPHone 6 Plus and to my suprise the `UIBubbleTableView` looks as weird as in the screen shot below.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this issue before? What could be done? I think the author has decided to discontinue the support for the lib. Any alternatives that has the features of UIBubbleTableView?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replace

```
(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in `UIBubbleTableView.m`. See `UIBubbleTableView` issue [UIBubbleTableView is not working with 64 bit os device](https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView/issues/73) 
Quote a comment from [another issue](https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView/issues/69) about issue reason :

> The problem is indeed the call to - (float)tableView:(UITableView
>   *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. When compiled for 64-bit, CGFloat is 64 bit, whereas float is only 32-bit.
>   The method signature doesn't match, so heightForRow is never called.
>   Changing it from float to CGFloat is exactly the right solution.

Comment: fixed the issue. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right, the author of UIBubbleTableView lib has been stopped support for it. Recently I've to make the similar kind of chat functionality into my app, I was satisfied with [SOMessaging](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMessaging) lib. Check it out. Its easy to customize and use. And yes, you can check out many other libs available [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/tags/chat). But out of them, I filtered some for this answer, kindly check its sample code (whichever fits as per your needs) here's [sphchatcollectionview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sphchatcollectionview), [jsqmessagesviewcontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jsqmessagesviewcontroller) and [notificationchat](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/notificationchat).